# how to access fetch value from database using mysql and this value use in same form any were

Tags: php, mysql

use query for access the $current_rank this value want to access in different query but this value can not access any where in different query so how to access $current_rank......

```
$query = "select * from menu_master where menu_id = 
          $row_id and hotel_id='" . $_REQUEST['hotel_id'] . "'";

$result = mysql_query($query)."<br/>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
     $rank = $row['set_rank'];
}
$current_rank = $rank;

//echo $current_id = $row_id."<br/>";
//echo $new_rank =$_REQUEST['set_rank']."<br/>";

$sql = "select * from menu_master where set_rank = '$new_rank ' and hotel_id='".$_REQUEST['hotel_id']."'" ; 
// echo  $sql."<br/>";

$rs = mysql_query($sql)."<br/>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{   
    $menu_id = $row['menu_id'];
    $sql="update menu_master 
    set set_rank=$current_rank where menu_id= $menu_id and hotel_id='".$_REQUEST['hotel_id']."'";
    //echo  $sql."<br/>";
    mysql_query($sql)."<br/>";
}

$sql="update menu_master set menu_name = '"  . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['menu_name']) . "', 
      menu_name_ar = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['menu_name_ar']) . "',
      is_active = '" . $is_active . "',
  set_rank = $new_rank where menu_id = '$current_id' and hotel_id='".$_REQUEST['hotel_id']."'";
    //echo  $sql."<br/>";
    //exit;
    mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Where else are you using the same??

Comment: Do you want all ranks retrieved from query or you want only last rank?

Comment: in this query want to use the $current_rank

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{   
    $menu_id = $row['menu_id'];
    $sql="update menu_master 
    set set_rank=$current_rank where menu_id= $menu_id and hotel_id='".$_REQUEST['hotel_id']."'";
    //echo  $sql."<br/>";
    mysql_query($sql)."<br/>";
}

Answer (score 0):

Your current_rank seems to be an array. If you have single value in current_rank, then do not use while loop for it.
Just use $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$current_rank = $row['set_rank'];

Answer (score 0):

Also you have commented out this line.
//echo $new_rank =$_REQUEST['set_rank']."
";
So you have no value for $new_rank